# Using database with Android app

Tags: android, database, mobile

I'm currently developing an android application. It stores user login and sign up information using Firebase.

The challenge I'm faced with is finding a suitable database to store information from websites which I would gather myself and allow the app to automatically update and include that information.

Firebase doesn't have a GUI that can create tables and records, so it does not fully meet my requirements. It'll only be used for user authentication.

I've read answers to questions similar to this and saw alternatives such as:

- **AWS**
- **Buddy**
- **Kinvey**

I currently don't have the budget to pay for a premium service so I'm looking for a free and reliable one until I can upgrade.

To sum it all up, I want a online database with either a GUI or text based (preferably SQL syntax), that is reliable and easy to understand.

Comment: sorry, but shopping lists are off topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my first Android app where I developed it from my diploma thesis and to learn about android philosophy I used MongodDB.

[MongoLab](http://mlab.com/) has free services to store your documents there. I used Java so you may have to look the MongoDB for java documentation, you can find it easy on the internet and the documentation is very explainable.

Also, for security reasons you may have to develop a restfull API and as a result you may have to use (for example) the PHP API of mongodb to cummunicate with a server and get the query results from there and use them for your Android app. You may have to search about how to get json data from a server to your android app but there are many tutorials about this too.

I have to mention that I am not an expert on which databases are the best to use for Android apps but MongoDB did the work for me.